# Count elements in a list matching some criteria, where the list is a row in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns. One of those columns contains lists, ie.

```
ID     CLASS     STRUCTURE
1      A         [1, 10, 15]
2      B         [3, 100, 5]
3      A         [25, 10, 1]
4      B         [100, 10000, 150]
```

I'd like to add a column indicating the count of elements in STRUCTURE that have a value of greater than 10, i.e.

```
ID     CLASS     STRUCTURE          COUNT
1      A         [1, 10, 15]        2
2      B         [3, 100, 5]        1
3      A         [25, 10, 1]        2
4      B         [100, 10000, 150]  3
```

To get a count of all numbers I can use .apply(sum) but I'm not sure how to apply within an apply, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `explode` then `groupby` with `sum`

```
df['new'] = df.STRUCTURE.explode().ge(10).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.apply()`

```
df['COUNT'] = df['STRUCTURE'].apply(lambda x: sum(e >= 10 for e in x))
```